# What's the best way to assign values to an object from another object in Angular?

Tags: javascript

below is part of my code

```
    this.diaryToEdit.diaryStatus.statusName = updatedDiary.diaryStatus.statusName;
    this.diaryToEdit.diaryStatus.statusId = updatedDiary.diaryStatus.statusId;
    this.diaryToEdit.actioDate = new Date(updatedDiary.actioDate);
    this.diaryToEdit.actionText = updatedDiary.actionText;
    this.diaryToEdit.diaryType = updatedDiary.diaryType;
```

Similary there are more properties which needs to be updated in `this.diaryToEdit` with `updatedDiary` values. Instead of writing like above, is there any better way to format code. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you could use spread syntax.

```
this.diaryToEdit = {...this.diaryToEdit, diaryType: updatedDiary.diaryType, actionText: updatedDiary.actionText}
```

note that this will create a new object with modified values.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs, i.e. if you want to clone the information first, or if you only need to keep some data contained in "updatedDiary", etc...

If it's okay (don't clone and keep any info) I'd probably re-write it like this:

```
this.diaryToEdit = {
    ...updatedDiary, 
    actioDate: new Date(updatedDiary.actioDate)
}
```

Otherwise it is better to create a clean copy:

```
let updatedDiaryClone = structuredClone(updatedDiary);
this.diaryToEdit = {
    diaryStatus: updatedDiaryClone.diaryStatus,
    actioDate: new Date(updatedDiaryClone.actioDate),
    actionText: updatedDiaryClone.actionText,
    diaryType: updatedDiaryClone.diaryType
}
```

But I repeat, it depends on your needs and possibly on the type of data you are cloning.